# Planning to buy new Lens for Nikon D5100

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100

Currently I am using Nikon D5100 DSLR camera with default kit lens 18-55MM lens.
Now I am planning to buy some new lens but i am confuse because still i am new to photography. Mainly I want to do landscape photography and sky photography.But since kit lens is not having very good zooming so can you just suggest me some economic lens which i can use with my Nikon D5100.

Please check out my sample picture and let me know that is this correct time to upgrade to lens of continue with kit lens and learn more.
 [Sample Photos](https://www.flickr.com/photos/deepakrathor/)

Comment: You could take a look on the following questions: [What's a good Nikon lens (DX) for a serious hobbyist landscape photographer?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1663/whats-a-good-nikon-lens-dx-for-a-serious-hobbyist-landscape-photographer) and [Looking for a good, cheap entry-level telephoto lens for Nikon D5100](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21100/looking-for-a-good-cheap-entry-level-telephoto-lens-for-nikon-d5100). I think these can give you some starting points, and feel free to ask if you still have some more specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sky and landscape photography, you would better buy a wide-angle lens. See [this link](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/simulator/) for a lens simulator that shows this visually. Try to find your working range with it, and then look for similar lenses.

I think you should stick to a single focal length, as you will notice that as soon as you have a wide angle, you pretty much operate it on the lowest focus length.

(I have recently tried a Tokina 11-16 DX II, and I loved the quality of pictures. I am planning to put up some eventually. Actually, I rented this from LensRentals.com, just to try out if I need this or a different lens, and probably I am going to buy one for the DX camera.)

Now, if you need zooming, I think the kit 18-105 is an extremely beautiful piece of lens for the price. Good overall performance, not excessively heavy, pretty reliable.

UPDATE: because the link of yours did not work the first time: definitely, you can use the 18-105mm for this type of photography. This is neither sky nor landscape though... :-)) He mostly does shallow DOF with some nice background. You can use the 105mm end for this photos, or use a fixed focal length lens with wide aperture. E.g. starting from 85mm 1/1.8.